# Problem typing a letter when expecting a number in C ++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, switch-statement

I am making a program which consists of making a menu to register and delete products from a store, I am just designing the menu with a switch, everything works fine up to there, the problem is that when I enter something other than a number as data ( letter or symbol) the console goes crazy; all the text starts to blink and it won't let me do anything (as if it was in a loop) and I have to close it.

Is there any way to avoid this? So when I enter a letter or symbol, it automatically detects it as invalid and shows me the message without the console going crazy?

By the way, I use Visual Studio.

Thanks in advance :)

```
#include<iostream>
#include<locale.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   
    int opc;

    cout << "                WELCOME TO THE STORE \"Happy Shopping\" ";
    cout << endl;
    

    cout << "\n1.- Create Order.";
    cout << "\n2.- Delate Order.";
    cout << "\n3.- list of orders created.";
    cout << "\n4.- Exit";
    cout << endl;
    cout << "\n¿what do you want to do?: "; cin >> opc;

    switch (opc)
    {

    case 1:cout << "\nCreate Order"; break;
    case 2:cout << "\nDelate Order"; break;
    case 3: cout << "\nlist of orders created"; break;
    case 4:exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    default:
        
        if ((opc != 1) && (opc != 2) && (opc != 3) && (opc != 4))
        {

            system("cls");

                cout << "the option entered is not valid, try again";
                return main();


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: By the way, `return main();` is not a good idea. I think you're trying to achieve recursion, but best not to try that with `main()`. Use a loop instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you make `opc` a `string` and take input as a string, you can manually check if the string is a number like so:

```
cin >> opc;
if (!isdigit(opc[0]) // since you're dealing with single-digit numbers, this should be fine
{
  cout << "You didn't enter a number!\n";
  // Any other error handling
}
```

`isdigit` is a function located in the `cctype` header file, so you should add `#include <cctype>` at the beginning of the file.

After this, you can convert `opc` to an integer with `stoi()`:

```
int opnum = stoi(opc);
// opnum is now the number, write the rest of the code such that it uses opnum
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe don't return main?

```
switch (opc)
{

case 1:cout << "\nCreate Order"; break;
case 2:cout << "\nDelate Order"; break;
case 3: cout << "\nlist of orders created"; break;
case 4:exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
default:
    system("cls");
    cout << "the option entered is not valid, try again";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As already said, you should not `return main()`. You may use a loop by testing your input for instance (surely one of the many solutions that may exist).

Also, you do not need the portion of code below :

```cpp
 // you do not need the if as you are already in the case !=1,2,3, or 4
 if ((opc != 1) && (opc != 2) && (opc != 3) && (opc != 4))
```

I provided you with an attempt, taken from your code, that may help to improve your code.
There might still be some bugs but it is a good starting point

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<locale.h>

int main()
{

    int opc=0;
    std::string input;

    std::cout << "                WELCOME TO THE STORE \"Happy Shopping\" ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
    // first display
    std::cout << "\n1.- Create Order.";
    std::cout << "\n2.- Delate Order.";
    std::cout << "\n3.- list of orders created.";
    std::cout << "\n4.- Exit";
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << "\n¿what do you want to do?: "; //cin >> opc;

    std::cin >> input;

    while ( input.length() > 0 )
    {
        // if we enter a string of more than length 1


        try
        {
            opc = std::stoi( input );

        }
        catch (...)
        {
            // mainly if the converted argument is not a number =>std::invalid_argument
            std::cout << "invalid value " << opc << std::endl;
        }
        std::cout << "you entered the value " << opc << std::endl;

        switch (opc)
        {

        case 1:
            std::cout << "\nCreate Order";
            break;
        case 2:
            std::cout << "\nDelate Order";
            break;
        case 3:
            std::cout << "\nlist of orders created";
            break;
        case 4:
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        default:
            // you do not need the if as you are already in the case !=1,2,3, or 4
            //if ((opc != 1) && (opc != 2) && (opc != 3) && (opc != 4))
            //{
            system("cls");
            // if you type things other than
            std::cout << "\n1.- Create Order.";
            std::cout << "\n2.- Delate Order.";
            std::cout << "\n3.- list of orders created.";
            std::cout << "\n4.- Exit";
            std::cout << std::endl;
            std::cout << "\n¿what do you want to do?: "; //cin >> opc;
        }

        std::cin >> input;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite that program that will pop up an error message to the user if the user input letters other than A,B,C, numbers and Special Characters on the field that require inputting a number or a letter

To choose whether a Rectangle, Circle or Cylinder the system will ask the user from your menu table

The menu tables as follows:

Choose your shape

A. Rectangle

B. Circle

C. Cylinder

X. Exit

If the user chooses either A,B,C and after he/she executes the program, your system will ask if he/she wants to continue and rerun the same shape again by pressing Y, go back to the main menu by pressing M or X for exit and the system will display "Your System is Terminated".